# Check what link did the user go to?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

You all know that the master page in MVC has this:

```
<nav>
     <ul id="menu">
         <li id="id1"><%: Html.ActionLink(...)%></li>
         <li id="id2"><%: Html.ActionLink(...)%></li>
         <li id="id3"><%: Html.ActionLink(...)%></li>
     </ul>
</nav>
```

How to check which tab did the user click? By checking the url or something else?
All of these links go to methods in different controllers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

document.location.href was all I needed.

Answer (score 1):

That method (action) will (usually) return a view which you will see as the output in your browser (unless you specify something else in your action method) .

There is no pages directly connected with a page request/link in ASP.NET MVC. I think you should understand some basic concepts of how MVC works.

When we request a page,the request is handled by an action method in a controller. Then action method will return the output and that will be displayed in the browser. The action method can simply return a "Hello World" string or a View which has some complex HTML markup. Returning View means Returning the contents of a file avalable in the View folder.

Remember ASP.NET MVC works on some conventions. So For example, IF we have a Controller called "User" and an action method Show like this

```
public class UserController
{
 public ActionResult Show()
 {
   return "Hello World";
 }

}
```

When the user browser for `yourdomainname/User/Show`, It will execute the Show Action method
of UserController and return the string "Hello World". So we will see "Hello World" in our browser.

What if we want to return a View ? We replace the Show method like this

```
 public ActionResult Show()
 {
   return View();
 }
```

As i told you earlier, we need to follow the convention now. That means, We have to create a View file in the `Views->User->Folder` with the name Show.cshtml. If this file exist, MVC will return that, else it will look for some shared folder in your views folder.

To Add a View, You can right click on your action method, and select "Add View" from the context menu

[image]

The one good thing is we can override the conventions, that means, IF you want to return a different view, you can specify the path when you call your View method.

Now go back to your question
Html.ActionLink is an HTML helper method which will outputs an anchor tag,

Ex  : `Html.ActionLink("Show User Info","Show","User")`

This will out put a link which  has a text Show User Info and will point to the `Show` Action method in `User` controller. So the output HTML markup of calling the above method will be

```
<a href="User/Show">Show User Info</a>
```

There are different overloads for this method.

**EDIT : For highlighting the link being clicked**

If you want to know which link is being clicked by coloring it or so, User a Partial View to Show your menus. And when you get an action call method, set a Property value in your Viewmodel which indicates which link is clicked, and in your View, use that view model to call the partial view.

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/30/asp-net-mvc-3-layouts-and-sections-with-razor.aspx

Comment: I think you didn't understand my question. I need to find out which link did the user went to. I know that by the links he can be shown different views and I know how to show them to him. But, I need a method which will color the tab which he clicked red. How to find out which is the tab he clicked on?

Comment: @Scrcee. You may use parial views in your Master page to show the Menu, and when u get an action method call,set some variable and pass that to your view. from that view, you call the partial view.